# How can I find source code folder within docker container when debugging in VScode

Tags: c++, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, containers

I have a containerized C++ application, I've build the image and also able to run the model executable file inside the container in windows prompt
I'm following [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial) to setup the debug in VScode.

If I use `ls -al` Ican see the source code files in it, but I use `docker diff`, it returns things like this:

```
docker diff container_name
C /root
A /root/.bash_history
```

There are huge amount of those stuff, but I can't find the source code folder that I can attach here:
[image]

Then I can only get this:
[image]

This doesn't look like a source code folder at all, what have I done wrong, I don't understand.

If I check the running container `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE    COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS       PORTS      NAMES
xxx             xxx    "/bin/bash" 21 minutes ago Up 13 minutes             xxx
```

I noticed '/bin/bash' looks strange to me, the folder I attached only contain some bash cache etc instead of the really source code, where did they go??? I'm so confused. I've been stuck with this for a whole afternoon. Can someone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the container is still running and has not been terminated or has not correctly been set up (or else `docker ps` might not list it), as a diagnostic tool, you can use the [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command, available from Docker 1.3 that allows to run a command to an existing running instance of a container. So you can open a shell, ssh, or just ls and explore its file system to understand what that running container instance is about.

While not a complete solution, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Attersson I've sorted it out, turns out I didn't use the right container.